# Real time vehicle tracking using google map showing vehicle moving on google map

Tags: jsf, richfaces, javabeans, ajax4jsf

I  am working on real time vehicle tracking project.

I am getting vehicle location after every 6 sec and I store lat and long in static variable each time.

I want to show vehicle moving on Google map after change location using ajax.
I have written code as:

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/" prefix="m"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<META HTTP-EQUIV=" " CONTENT="6">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAtRLgopSfFn_inKV4Mb4dwRQrh986W3YN5ROngdOVRv-81htxfBSHsTcVUm4HRkCt9bSp5mP_3_snrw"
type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body>

<f:view>
    <h:form id="aaaa">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <m:map id="mp" width="500px" height="500px" latitude="  #{mp3.lat} "
                longitude=" #{mp3.lon}" zoom="15">
                <m:mapControl name="GMapTypeControl" />
                <m:mapControl name="GLargeMapControl"
                    position="G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_RIGHT" />

                <m:marker id="m" latitude="  #{mp3.lat} " longitude=" #{mp3.lon}">

    <m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="Start<br>  " />

               <a4j:support event="onchange" action="  " reRender="m"></a4j:support>

                </m:marker>
            </m:map>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Start" action="#{mp3.meth}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Path Map" action="pathmp" />
    </h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is how to move vehicle marker on google map using ajax a4j without reloading all page?

technology i have used are
- jsf
- richfaces
- a4j
- javaBean

Thanks

Comment: Can it is possible by using polling